# How do I share any type of file(.pdf,.xls,.docs) through intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I checked many times but everyone asked how to open and read these files.
But I just want to choose a file from my phone's storage and share it.

I tried using the following code

```
void sendIntent5() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          String Pathholder = intent.getData().getPath();
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(Pathholder);
        intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "application/pdf");
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

But I only got the following error :
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference

Comment: try to log PathHolder

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh hehe NPE is sooner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Anyway its all wrong ... read some official tutorials first ... you are createing new Intent which obviously have null as data ... you prolly need intent from onActivityResult

Comment: @Selvin why does a intent needed from onActivtyResult?

Comment: @Selvin Can you please share a snippet?

Comment: No, already there is pleanty similar questions ... also there is official guide on the topic How to *choose a file from my phone's storage*

Comment: also, intent.getData() already returns Uri object, why do you getPath() from Uri and then get Uri from that path?